# How can I know which program is sniffing packets?

Tags: linux, networking

I found the NIC of a machine is running in promiscuous mode, now how can I locate the program who is actually capturing packets?

Comment: Suspect tcpdump and wireshark, if not I would try lsof and netstat, good luck :)

Comment: Does this help? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48250/find-processes-using-a-network-interface

Answer (score 5):

You could try running [lsof(1)](http://www.netadmintools.com/html/lsof.man.html) and checking all processes which have sockets open as `SOCK_RAW`. This will most likely give you at least one false positive, in case you're running some kind of a DHCP-client, but it will reveal processes running a network interface in promiscuous mode too.

Try something like this:

```
sudo lsof -Pnl | grep SOCK_RAW
```

Comment: SOCK_RAW would appear to be a way to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114804/reading-from-a-promiscuous-network-device